# how do I turn the 2 grids around on their side?

Tags: html, css, grid

Need the Portfolio and Services buttons turned around to lie horizontally and in line with the About Us and Contacts buttons.

I can provide the CSS if needed.

**Preview of what the website looks now:**

[image: Preview]

### very confusing

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html lang="en">
 <head>
 <title>Home</title>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <link rel="icon" href="images/favicon.ico">
 <link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/favicon.ico" />
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
 <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
 <script src="js/jquery-migrate-1.1.1.js"></script>
 <script src="js/superfish.js"></script>
 <script src="js/jquery.equalheights.js"></script>
 <script src="js/jquery.easing.1.3.js"></script>
 <script>


 </script>
 <!--[if lt IE 8]>
   <div style=' clear: both; text-align:center; position: relative;'>
     <a href="http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/internet-explorer/products/ie/home?           strong textocid=ie6_countdown_bannercode">
       <img src="http://storage.ie6countdown.com/assets/100/images/banners/warning_bar_0000_us.jpg" border="0" height="42" width="820" alt="You are using an outdated browser. For a faster, safer browsing experience, upgrade for free today." />
     </a>
  </div>
<![endif]-->
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
  <script src="js/html5shiv.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="css/ie.css">

<![endif]-->
 </head>
 <body  class="page1">
<!--==============================header=================================-->
 <header> 
 <div class="container_12">
 <div class="grid_12">

</div>
<div class="grid_4">
  <div class="port"><div>
    <a class="link_img" href="index-2.html"><img src="images/page1_img1.jpg" alt="">      

<span></span></a>
    <a href="index-1.html" class="maxheight link1">About Us</a>
  </div>
</div></div>
<div class="grid_4"><h1><a href="index.html"><img src="images/logo.png" alt="Brand
    Identity"></a></h1></div>
<div class="grid_4 fright">
  <div class="port">
    <a class="link_img " href="index-2.html"> <img src="images/page1_img2.jpg" alt="">
                        <span></span></a>
    <a href="index-6.html" class="maxheight link1">Contacts</a>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="clear"></div>
<div class="port1">
  <div class="grid_12">
  <div class="port">
    <a class="link_img " href="index-2.html"><img src="images/page1_img3.jpg" alt="">
  <span></span></a>
    <a href="index-2.html" class="link1 ">Portfolio</a>
  </div>
  <div class="port">
    <a class="link_img " href="index-2.html"><img src="images/page1_img4.jpg" alt="">
    <span></span></a>
    <a href="index-4.html" class="link1 ">Services</a></div>
  </div>
    </div>
    <div class="port2">
  <div class="grid_12">
  <div class="port">
    <a class="link_img " href="index-2.html"><img src="images/page1_img5.jpg" alt=""> 
    <span></span></a>
    <a href="index-3.html" class="link1 ">Work for PixelMi<sup>2</sup></a>
  </div>
  <div class="port">
    <a class="link_img " href="index-2.html"><img src="images/page1_img6.jpg" alt="">
    <span></span></a>
    <a href="index-5.html" class="link1 ">Blog</a></div>
  </div>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="ic"></div>
  </header>
```

```
  <footer>    
 <div class="container_12">
<div class="grid_12">
<div class="socials">
  <a href="#"></a>
  <a href="#"></a>
  <a href="#"></a>
  <a href="#"></a>
</div>
  <div class="copy">

  </div>
</div>
 </div>
</footer>

</body>
 </html>
```

Comment: Make a http://www.jsfiddle.net. Thanks

Comment: Here ya go - http://jsfiddle.net/ScarlettAki/8g5L8/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ScarlettAki/y77aR/1/    Are you able to view it?  Its not showing up as public on my profile

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ScarlettAki/y77aR/4/

Comment: nearly there. you've got a lot of CSS in the JS panel. As for the external references (at the top of your page) see if there is an online version you can link to. Thanks!

Comment: [pixelmi2.com](http://www.pixelmi2.com) Arigato x 1,000!!!!!! Been trying to figure this out for days! :Z